# Is it possible in WPF to have a Panel and be able to add UserControls to it (Similar to Windows Forms)?

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I'm going to be making a user control for person information, I will then populate a panel of some sort with the ammount of people found (one user control for each person).

Can WPF handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this, but it is not necessarily the best option.

Instead of putting in controls per person, you can use an ItemTemplate that describes how to render a "Person".  You can then just bind a (standard) ItemsControl, such as a ListBox or ListView to your collection of people directly, and WPF will handle wiring it up for you.

For details, I'd recommend reading up on [Data Binding on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278072(VS.95).aspx), in particular, ["Binding to Collections."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278072(VS.95).aspx#binding_to_collections)